# c# Sending emails with authentication. standard approach not working

Tags: c#, security, email

I am trying to send an email using the following very standard code.  However, I get the error that follow...

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

message.Sender = new MailAddress("sen@der.com");
message.To.Add("reci@pient.com");
message.Subject = "test subject";
message.Body = "test body";

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "mail.myhost.com";
//client.Port = 587;

NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential();

cred.UserName = "sen@der.com";
cred.Password = "correct password";
cred.Domain = "mail.myhost.com";
client.Credentials = cred;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;     

client.Send(message);
```

---

> Mailbox unavailable. The server
>   response was:  No such
>   user here.

This recipient email address definitely works.  To make this account work I had to do some special steps in outlook.  Specifically, I had to do change account settings -> more settings -> outgoing server -> my outgoing server requires authentication & use same settings.  I am wondering if there is some other strategy.

I think the key here is that my host is Server Intellect and I know that some people on here use them so hopefully someone else has been able to get through this.  I did talk to support but they said with coding issues I am on my own :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...

```
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(); 

cred.UserName = "sen@der.com"; 
cred.Password = "correct password"; 
//cred.Domain = "mail.myhost.com";
```

... you should not need to provide the `.Domain` unless you are using Kerberos or some other complex authentication.

**Edit...**

Check out my extended [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575159/code-to-send-email/2575169#2575169).  It has an example of how to send an email with authentication.  It's also has SSL enabled so you may need to remove that part.

Answer (score 0):

there is no mailbox called `sen@der.com` on server `mail.myhost.com`, check that

Comment: how do you know? You can configure every MTA (you own) to accept mails for every domain you like.

Comment: Whether you can configure your own MTA to accept mail for some other domain doesn't matter.  The sending code will still do an MX record lookup to determine which is the real server to send the mail to.

Comment: @Oliver i know it from "The server response was: No such user here"

Comment: You're right, i skipped that part in the question that he got this error message.